# MySQL count values and put custom columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have this query:

```
SELECT count(password) as normal, count(fb_id) as fb, count(google_id) as google, count(linkedin_id) as linkedin FROM `users`
```

which returns (correctly) :

```
normal | fb | google | linkedin     
-------------------------------
2      |  2 |   1    | 1
```

Now what if I want to group them in custom columns?
Like:

```
type     | count
------------
fb       | 2
normal   | 2
google   | 1
linkedin | 1
```

I do not have such columns in my table, so I have to get them somehow in the query. Is it even possible?

Comment: Do you have a specific ordering in your output, or does it not matter?

Comment: @Dreg Korig is there any reason why you accepted the latest answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `UNION` of four queries. Do a try:

```
SELECT 'normal' as `type`, count(password) as `count` FROM `users`
UNION
SELECT 'fb' as `type`, count(fb_id) as `count` FROM `users`
UNION
SELECT 'google' as `type`, count(google_id) as `count` FROM `users`
UNION
SELECT 'linkedin' as `type`, count(linkedin_id) as `count` FROM `users`
```

Answer (score 0):

With UNION ALL:

```
SELECT 'fb' as type, count(fb_id) as count FROM `users`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'normal', count(password) FROM `users`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'google', count(google_id) FROM `users`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'linkedin', count(linkedin_id) FROM `users`
```